# set the path of a particular executable in csh

Tags: path, csh, setenv

Currently, I have make a non-root installation of an updated version of autoconf on the user home directory of the UNIX workstation. The workstation has an older version of autoconf which is to be executed as default.

How could I change the path in .cshrc so that the autoconf I execute would be pointed to the updated version that I installed instead of the older version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your non-root install is `$HOME/my/autoconf/bin` then something like this will work:

```
set path = ( $HOME/my/autoconf/bin $PATH )
```